# How to keep the legs healthy when climbing stairs

Tags: legs, shoes, stairs

My favorite sport is climbing staircases by foot, then going down by elevator and going up again by feet, etc. I feel it hurts the legs much less than jogging, since I don't 'fall' on my legs while climbing.

Still, I would like to do if there are any risks of leg injuries when climbing stairs?

In particular, what kind of shoes are best suited for this kind of sport? Currently I use simple walking shoes (not running shoes), is this good enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its great that you love running up the stairs. You are correct that coming down has a slight negative effect on the legs specifically the knees. 
Running up for that matter,  has very less impact on your joints,  unless you stomp. The majority of the pressure is on your calf muscles, which is obviously a good thing... Over time your muscles grow stronger. 
You should also check out competitive stair climbing called "tower running". Where athletes from all over the world compete in climbing famous towers.

Regarding the shoes,  there is no specific standard but i would recommend a flat sole with powerful grip so as to avoid any accidents due to tripping. 
Best of luck and enjoy the climb!